# HTTPS Request issue = requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a react app on S3 while backend is running on EC2 (node) when I use S3 over HTTP it works and shows content even with route53 over http it works.

If I access domain over HTTPS via route53 it doesnt load the page. I have attached SSL with route 53 but no use.

I have also tried using cloud front and used SSL with it too yet I receive same error.

Error As Follow

> "Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
> requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request
> has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: You can't mix https with http. Your website is using both.

Comment: What I need to do here to resolve this?

Comment: You have to search through your application source code, and replace http links with valid https links.